# How to get list of usb devices connected from a service

Tags: android, android-service, usbmanager

I am writing a **service** which would send some proprietary commands to a specific USB device connected to Android based box. 
Earlier I had implemented an app (with Activity) so it was pretty straightforward:

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

My main class:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
 ..
 mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);

}
```

And I end up with :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference

Now without an activity I am not finding any ways to get an instance of UsbManager.

Is there a way to do this in a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getApplicationContext` does work in `protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` so you have to use below method to get `getApplicationContext`-

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
mContext = getApplicationContext();
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```